# htaccess rewrite Language to domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my website to a another domain, when the language is changed.

Example:
**mywebsite.de/en/page1**
should go to:
**mywebsite.com/en/page1**

So if "en" occurs in url path, the rewriting should happen.

I have this, but this only works on on Homepage, not with subdirectories.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.de$
RewriteRule ^en$ https://www.mywebsite.com/en?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.de$
RewriteRule ^en(.+)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/en$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Flag R: redirect if pattern `^en(.+)$` matches.

Flag QSA: append query string

Flag L: last rule and stop processing the rule set

See also: [RewriteRule Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)